# Angular 2 http - send request conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-http

Hello I needed to deal with HTTP. I need send request using condition here is example:

I need send `POST /api/files` - but sending is conditional on the server api: 
`GET /api/condition` - return true or false. If return true it is possible to call `/api/files` and when is false i need call `POST /api/enable.`

1 . GET /api/condition

1 a. return true -> 2.

1 b. return false -> 3.

2 . POST /api/files

3 . POST/api/enable -> 1.

The simplest way is like as:

```
load(){
 http.get(/api/condition).subscribe(response => {
   if(response == true)
      http.post(/api/files).subscribe()
    else http.post(/api/enable).subscribe(x => this.load())
  })
 }
```

But it is not clear solution. It is any way how to create this? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you got the code working the only thing you could do is to modularise the whole block and split it into proper functions.

**Check condition request**

```
fetchCondition(): Observable<boolean> {
   return http.get(/api/files).map((response: boolean) => response);
}
```

**Fetch files**

```
fetchFiles(): Observable<YourFile[]> {
   return http.post(/api/files).map((response: YourFile[]) => response);
}
```

**Enable files fetching**

```
enable(): Observable<any> {
   http.post(/api/enable).map((response: any) => response);
}
```

**Logic - put the pieces together**

```
load(){
   this.fetchCondition().subscribe(
       condition => {
          if(condition) {
             this.fetchFiles().subscribe(
                files => this.doSomethingWithFiles(files),
                err => { /* handle */ }
             );
          } else {
             this.enable().subscribe(resp => this.load());
          }
       },
       err => { /* handle */ }
   );
}
```

**Note that you can get into inifinite loop!**
Running the load function might get you in infinite loop if your server somehow fails to enable the condition you're examing at the very beginning of your function.
I would recommend some kind of counter / scheduler that would take care of this kind of vulnerability. Of course it all depends on the context and complexity of your app.

Answer (score 1):

The post method returns a cold observable so requires calling subscribe for it to execute. So what you have is the simplest way. You could do some minor refactoring but the core principles would remain the same